# Hive scanning entire data for bucketed table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I was trying to optimize a hive SQL by bucketing the data on a single column. I created the table with following statement

```
CREATE TABLE `source_bckt`(
  `uk` string, 
  `data` string)
CLUSTERED BY(uk) SORTED BY(uk) INTO 10 BUCKETS
```

Then inserted the data after executing `"set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;"`

When I run the following select `"select * from source_bckt where uk='1179724';"`
Even though the data is supposed to be in a single file which can be identified by the following equation `HASH('1179724')%10` the mapreduce spawned scans through the entire set of files.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This optimization is not supported yet.
Current JIRA ticket status is **PATCH AVAILABLE**

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5831

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. so is it safe to assume that as it stands, bucketing is not going to give performance improvement over non bucketed table in this scenario? I already partitioned and created a ORC file, any other performance improvement you think will be advisable?

Comment: Yep, no performance gain here. BTW - theoretically if the data is not only bucketed but also sorted, the data retrieval for a specific value could be log(n), but it doesn't seem to be part of the JIRA ticket scope. P.s. this use-case seems much more adequate to HBase than Hive.